# Как в opengl в связке с с++(QTWidget) прорисовать объект сферу?

Tags: c++, opengl, qtcreator

Как в opengl в связке с с++(QTWidget) прорисовать объект сферу? Не могу найти аналог WireSphere в с#.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему вопрос по Qt 3D. (qtcreator это просто IDE. на нем ничего не пишется)
Почитайте вот это:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-basicshapes-cpp-example.html

А вообще при установке qt можно было поставить и примеры. По крайней мере найдете направление "куда копать"